# Eclipse 2021/03 JavaScript not Supporting

Tags: javascript, eclipse

eclipse not provide supports for old .js file
all is have to create new one for it

[image]

here is newly created  file

[image]

help me sir  and please don't give negative points  help me

how can i provide support for JS

Comment: Make sure to open the `.js` file with the Generic Text Editor (right-click + _Open With > ..._) to get JavaScript support. Please note, you have installed at least one Genuitec plugin (the dark theme) that patches Eclipse at runtime which might slow down Eclipse and cause issues. Only in older versions Eclipse remembered the editor per file (like in your case).

Comment: thank you so much sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Darkest Dark theme you will lose support for JS.